# Zend Framework Query

Tags: php, zend-framework

Can anyone help me to do this in the right way?I mean.. like that : $db->select()->group..... I tried a few times, but doesn't work for me :(

> $this->q->fetchAll('select * from clubs, club_photos_default where clubs.id=club_photos_default.c_id group by clubs.id');

Best Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way in this case is the way you're doing it, since the whole SQL query is known and static.

You are not required to use `Zend_Db_Select` to build queries procedurally.  In fact, it's often more complex and less readable than just typing out the literal SQL query.

Use `Zend_Db_Select` when you *need* to build a query procedurally, based on variables and logic in your application code.

But to answer your question, this should work:

```
$select = $db->select()
  ->from(array('c'=>'clubs'))
  ->join(array('p'=>'club_photos_default'), 'c.id=p.c_id')
  ->group('c.id');
$this->q->fetchAll($select);
```

(Assuming `$db` is an object of `Zend_Db_Adapter`.)